# Add leading zero to current post display

Tags: loop

I am using the next to show in a loop of posts the current post and the total of posts published.

```
$post_query = new WP_Query($args);

$postAmount = wp_count_posts( 'post' )->publish;

<?php echo $post_query->current_post + 1 ?> / <?php echo $postAmount ?>
```

This returns 1/20, 2/20, etc

Does someone know how to add a leading zero so it shows 01/20, 02/20, etc?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should work with `sprintf('%02d', $post_query->current_post + 1)`

Comment: Works like a charm. You saved my day! Thank you